# Using "@" to get system property

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a project that is successfully using the following to retrieve a system properties.

```
<property name="blah" value="@some.system.property@"/>
```

This looks like it might be using a custom property placeholder with a prefix and suffix of `@` but I don't find one in the context. I have searched the SPEL reference and don't see this syntax referenced.

Is this something built into Spring and if so where is the reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Maven, that is one of the default placeholder markers which Maven can substitute during the [`process-resources` phase](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html):

> Since the '@' delimiter is the same on both ends, we don't need to specify '@*@' (though we can).

It's phrased rather poorly as a hypothetical of how to use the resources mojo, but it accurately reflects the default behavior.

Comment: To add one more link, this is referred to as `filtering`: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html